# Extracting Date and Time in R

Tags: r

**Background:**
I'm currently learning R and I have a dataframe called `data_2014` that looks like this

[image]

This was a result of reading csv files using read_csv from the package tidyverse

**Question:** I want to add separate columns for year, month, date, hour, minute, second by extracting the components from the date_time column. I have attempted to do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

 data_2014 <- data_2014 %>%
  mutate(
    date_new = as.Date(date_time, tryformats = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M%S"),
    year = year(date_new),
    month = month(date_new),
    date = mday(date_new),
    hours = hour(date_new),
    minutes = minute(date_new),
    seconds = second(date_new)
  )
```

This gives me a lot of NA values and the year column does not appear properly. How should I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post images of data or code.  Make it "copy-and-paste"-able.

Comment: I'll take note of that next time (first time posting). Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: My pleasure, and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: You need not wait until next time to fix the image issue.  Please ***edit** this question* to replace the screenshot with their textual equivalents. When you are done, you can delete your comment to help keep the question clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `as.Date` can be

```
 as.Date(date_time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

as there are `:` between the time components

e.g.

```
as.Date("4/1/2015 0:00:15", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2015-04-01"
as.Date("4/1/2015 0:00:15", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M%S")
#[1] NA
```

In addition, the argument is `tryFormats`

```
as.Date("4/1/2015 0:00:15", tryFormats = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-04-01"
```

instead of `tryformats`

```
as.Date("4/1/2015 0:00:15", tryformats = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "0004-01-20"
```

---

If we want to extract the time components, as well, convert it to `POSIXct` instead of `Date` class

i.e.

```
data_2014 %>%
  mutate(
    date_new = as.POSIXct(date_time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    year = year(date_new),
    month = month(date_new),
    date = mday(date_new),
    hours = hour(date_new),
    minutes = minute(date_new),
    seconds = second(date_new)
  )
```

---

Or if we are using `lubridate`, use `mdy_hms`

```
 data_2014 %>%
  mutate(
    date_new = mdy_hms(date_time),
    year = year(date_new),
    month = month(date_new),
    date = mday(date_new),
    hours = hour(date_new),
    minutes = minute(date_new),
    seconds = second(date_new)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm getting all 0's for hour, minute, and second. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @S10000 Instead of converting to `Date` you may need `as.POSIXct`

Comment: @S10000 Please try the updated code